Nginx cache entry after header update
Nginx cache with proxy_cache_background_update on;
some api response that has Cache-Control=max-age=7, public, stale-while-revalidate=59. After a while upstream response changes header for the same resource to Cache-Control=private, no-cache, must-revalidate. Nginx will continue to serve old stale content and never return new non-cachable response.
Is it possible return new response and not staled cached response when headers change?
#default_location
proxy_cache_background_update on;
proxy_cache_use_stale updating error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_429;
proxy_cache_lock on;


you can try proxy_cache_bypass
see the below guide it will help you to configure it:
https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/584/nginx-configure-bypassing-purging-proxy-cache-ngx_cache_purge

i know how to configure it, but i don't see how it has connection with my question. Can you please elaborate.

If I understand correctly, You want to bypass Nginx cache based on cache-control headers from upstream.
For that, get the value of cache-control, if it contains no-cache directive then set proxy_cache_bypass to 1. Here's the config,
http{

  map $http_cache_control $bypass_cache {
     no-cache   1;
     default 0; #if no-cache directive is not present then serve from cache
  }

  server{
     proxy_cache_bypass $bypass_cache;
  }
}


when using proxy_cache_background_update on; we don't have access to upstream headers like this

@Axon what do you mean by not having access? also can you post the complete config?
